# Copy files between cloud storage providers

Tags: api, cloud, cloud-storage

I need to upload a large number of files to one cloud storage provider and then copy those files to another cloud storage provider using software that I will write. I have looked at several cloud storage providers and I don't see an easy way to do what I need to do unless I first download the files and then upload them to the second storage provider. I want to copy directly using cloud storage provider API's. Any suggestions or links to storage providers that have API's that will allow copying from one provider to another would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write code for it use Google's gsutil :

> The gsutil cp command allows you to copy data between your local file
>   system and the cloud, copy data within the cloud, and copy data
>   between cloud storage providers.

You will find detailed info in this link :

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

If you want a software, use Multicloud. https://www.multcloud.com/

It can download directly from the web and it can also transfer the file from one cloud storage like dropbox to another like google drive.

Cloud HQ also as a chrome extension is one of the best solutions to sync your data between clouds. You can check it out.

Answer (score 1):

There is several option you could choose. First using cloud transfer services such as Multi Cloud. I've using it to transfer from AWS S3 or Egnyte to Google Drive.

1. Multicloud https://www.multcloud.com which is free to for 30GB data traffic per month.
2. Mountain duck https://mountainduck.io/ if connector are available you could mount each cloud services as your hard drive, and move each file easily.

I hope this could help.

Comment: Do these services really AVOID copying files to local machine (defined as the machine on which the ACTUAL AGENT is running - your computer if it is a CLI application or ANOTHER cloud if it's SaaS), or do they merely HIDE the fact that they are doing a plain old download/upload under the hood?

Comment: Option 1 (Multicloud) there is no copy or background process on your local machine. it's working on cloud to cloud seamlessly.
Option 2 (Mountain Duck) is mounted, actual data is on the cloud. But i'm not recommend for too large or too much files.